# PHP AJAX display a value when certain value is selected in drop down list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im making a subjects schedule what it does is the user select his/her desired course and the subjects that is offered in the selected course are displayed in the drop down list that part is working fine, the problem is when I select a certain subject I need to show in text field the units of that selected subject the code im about to show here is working but it show as drop down list but I want to make as text field i dont know to make it as a text field.

here is my code

**select subject**

```
<select name="subject" id="subject1" class="form-control m-1">
             <option value="">Select Subject</option>
</select>
```

**part where I want to show subject unit**

```
<input name="unit" id="unit1" class="form-control m-1">
```

**AJAX for subject**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subject1').change(function(){
      var subject=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_unit.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{Units:subject},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#unit1').val(data);
        }
      });

    });
  });
```

**fetch_unit.php**

```
<?php
include 'admin/includes/server.php';

$output='';
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_subject";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo $output=$row["units"];



?>
```

Comment: `i want to make it as text field..` ? can you elaborate it more ?

Comment: @Swati yes I want to make it as a text field because the code that is working for me is the units shows a dropdown list but I want to make it as a text field I got a 1 specified unit per subject it will be nonsense if it is a dropdownlist , I hope I explained it better sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: so does your current code work or not ? Also, you need to get your subject in your php code using `$_POST['Units']` and pass the same in your query i.e where clause.

Comment: @Swati the code above is updated and its working now

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#subject1').change(function(){
      var subject=$(this).val();
      $.ajax({
       url:"fetch_unit.php",
       method:"post",
       data:{Units:subject},
       dataType:"text",
      success:function(data){
        $('#unit1').append(data);
      }
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: I'll try this I'll let you know if I get it to work thanks :)

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify AJAX `success()` function:

```
success:function(data)
{ 
    $('#unit1').text(data);   // fill #unit1 with PHP response data
}
```

And in PHP use `implode()` for creating a string:

```
$row = [];
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $row[] = $row['units'];
}
echo isset($_POST['units']) && $_POST['units'] ? rtrim(implode(', ',$row),', ') : '';
```

```js
$(()=>{

    $('#subject1').change(function(){

        var subject=$(this).val();

        $.ajax({
          url:"fetch_unit.php",
          method:"post",
          data:{units:subject}, 
          success:function(data)
          {
              $('#unit1').html('');
              $('#unit1').text(data);
          }
        });

    });
});
```

```html
<select name="subject" id="subject1" class="form-control m-1">
             <option value="">Select Subject</option>
             <option value="Subject">Subject</option>
</select>

<div id='unit1' class="form-control m-1"></div>
```

In PHP you can use `$_POST['units']` variable, which contains `#subject1 value`